# SQL date constants constants in memory

Tags: apex, datetime

I am able to run a query with a where clause

```
Opportunity.CloseDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7
```

However, I have a custom date attribute for  custom object.  When I try to set this value in memory:

```
digest.DM_Digest_date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:7;
```

I get:

```
expecting a semi-colon, found ':'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date constants/literals make sense only in the context of a query.
If by "in memory" you mean Apex code, then something like this is needed:

```
digest.DM_Digest_date__c = System.today() - 7;
```

or

```
digest.DM_Digest_date__c = Date.newInstance(2012,12,31);
```

You can read up more about [Date class's methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm) (plus [System](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm) class has `today()` and `now()` methods too).

---

Not to mention the fact that [`LAST_N_DAYS`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) etc all cover timespans, not actual points in time... They're really just a way to quickly write `WHERE CreatedDate > :startPoint AND CreatedDate < :endPoint`. So you can't really assign this to one date/time variable, you'd need 2 fields if you want to record a date "from-to".

Answer (score 0):

I am able to query on a custom date field okay

```
Select Id, Name from Opportunity where Lookup__r.Start_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:7
```

Can you double check that it is indeed a Date field. Also, that the relational reference is correct (does it need an __r ?)

Perhaps, it might also be an idea to post your query.